# How to Read Json inside a Json in Spark RDD?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have this sample data:
Saved as `test.json`

```
{
    "memberId": "Test0001",
    "params": {"field1":"testField","field2":"testField2"}
    "withoutValueSample": {}
}
```

This is how I read it in Spark:

```
val session: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val inputRdd: RDD[Row] = session.read.json(test.json).rdd
```

I know this is how to get the memberId:
`inputRdd.forEach(i => i.getString(0))`

However, I don't know how to get the value of "params" and "withoutValueSample". I tried doing the `.get(<index>).asInstanceOf[JsonObject]` but I'm getting this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to io.circe.JsonObject`

How do I get the params, and the withoutValueSample? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

In spark DataFrame, JSON objects read as `Row` objects, so you can access inner JSON just like below:

- `inputRdd.forEach(i => i.getAs[Row](1))`
- or `inputRdd.forEach(i => i.getAs[Row]("params"))`.

(ps: `i` inside your code is actually also a `Row` object.)